# Stability of Merge sort

Tags: mergesort, stability

Is merge sort stable? I read it in a book which says merge sort is stable as long as the merge operation implemented properly. Is that true?

Comment: read the wiki page...

Comment: It's not an in place sorting algorithm, so perhaps by requiring a larger chunk of memory we can say it is as unstable as the memory it requires.

Comment: @ReyGonzales I don't think that's what were talking about when we are assessing the stability of a sorting algorithm. And even then, most sorting algorithms that are not in place tend to be stable, such as merge sort.

Answer (score 8):

true. It depends on how you properly implement the merge sort. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability